# How to encode / decode scalar values

Tags: encoding, machine-learning, tensorflow

I am trying to use an lstm-encoder to read ebay-auction data (incl. scalar inputs) and predict the final price of the auctioned product.

Thus, both on the encoder as well as on the decoder side I need to work with scalars (sizes, amounts and above all prices).

How would I go and encode / decode scalars? They are of all ranges and sizes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure LSTM is the right model for you. However, if you want to do it, you can use the many to one model.

You need to make the inputs in the same format, so you can feed them into each LSTM cell.

Finally, use the output from the last cell.

[image: The slide is from http://cs231n.stanford.edu/.]
The slide is from http://cs231n.stanford.edu/.

It's not exactly the same, but you may find a similar example at https://github.com/nlintz/TensorFlow-Tutorials/blob/master/7_lstm.py. (28x28 images to 10 labels)

Comment: Thx Sung Kim. However, my issue is not to choose the mopdel, but to chose the encoding. 

Imagine the (correct) result was 6.30 or 120 or 123,555. So I want the output of the many-to-one-model to be able to give scalars in this range. 
How would I organize these numbers. Would I want the output-cell itself to be give that number? I guess no as outputs usually are in the dimension of -1 to 1 or similar, right?

Comment: You need to add one more layer (output[-1]*W+b) to predict values from -1 to 1 or any values you want. Something like this:     return tf.matmul(outputs[-1], W) + B, lstm.state_size # State size to initialize the stat. Based on the W, you can get one scalar value.

Comment: Thx for the hint. Seems straight forward. Cant get a scalar out though, always getting tensors again. Tried to dot product...

Comment: try to get one dimensional tensor. :-)

Comment: Still at his. What I do follows your suggestion. I take the normal seq2seq-model and then "steal" the hidden state at end of encoding to ALSO predict a price range. Works on synthetic data so far.

However, I also need the seq2seq-decoder output and that works best with attention, effectively bypassing the many-to-one-exit (=hidden state at end of encoding). I published a specific question and would be happy if you looked into that (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37309086/seq2seq-attention-peeping-into-the-encoder-states-bypasses-last-encoder-hidden-s). 

Thx a bunch