# seq2seq-Attention peeping into the encoder-states bypasses last encoder-hidden-state

Tags: python, tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network

In the seq2seq-Model I want to use the hidden state at end of encoding to read out further info from the input sequence.

So I return the hidden state and build a new sub net on top of it. That works decently well. However, I have a doubt: This is supposed to become more complex, thus I am effectively relying of having ALL the necessary information for the additional task to be encoded in that hidden state.

If, however, the seq2seq-decoder uses the attention mechanism, it basically peeps into the encoder side, effectively bypassing the hidden state at end of encoding. Thus NOT ALL the info the seq2seq-network relies on is encoded in the hidden state at end of encoding.

Does that, in theory, mean that I have to not use the attention mechanism but go with plain-vanilla-seq2seq in order to get the maximum out of the hidden state at end of encoding? This would obviously sacrifice a big part of the effectiveness on the seq2seq-task.

Just trying to get a doubt confirmed I am having. Basically: Normally the last encoder-hidden-state in the seq2seq-model would contain ALL relevant info for decoding. But with attention this is no longer the case, right?

And on a more speculative note, do you agree with these possible solutions:
- Create an additional attention mechanism for the new sub net?
- Or, alternatively, use a convolution over all the hidden states of the encoder-side as additional input to the new sub net?

Any thoughts? Easier fixes?

Thx

Answer (score 2):

Bottom line, you should try different approaches and see what model works best for your data. Without knowing anything about your data or running some tests it is impossible to speculate on whether attention mechanism, CNN, etc. provides any benefits or not.

However, if you are using the tensorflow seq2seq models available in  [tensorflow/tensorflow/python/ops/seq2seq.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/ops/seq2seq.py)  let me share some observations about the attention mechanism as implemented in `embedding_attention_seq2seq()` and `attention_decoder()` that related to your question(s):

1. Hidden state of decoder is initialized with the final state of encoder...so attention does not "effectively bypass the hidden state at end of encoding" IMHO

The following code in `embedding_attention_seq2seq()` passes in the last time step `encoder_state` as the `initial_state` in the 2nd argument:

```
  return embedding_attention_decoder(
      decoder_inputs, encoder_state, attention_states, cell,
      num_decoder_symbols, embedding_size, num_heads=num_heads,
      output_size=output_size, output_projection=output_projection,
      feed_previous=feed_previous,
      initial_state_attention=initial_state_attention)
```

And you can see that `initial_state` is used directly in `attention_decoder()` without going through any kind of attention states:

```
state = initial_state

...

for i, inp in enumerate(decoder_inputs):
  if i > 0:
    variable_scope.get_variable_scope().reuse_variables()
  # If loop_function is set, we use it instead of decoder_inputs.
  if loop_function is not None and prev is not None:
    with variable_scope.variable_scope("loop_function", reuse=True):
      inp = loop_function(prev, i)
  # Merge input and previous attentions into one vector of the right size.
  input_size = inp.get_shape().with_rank(2)[1]
  if input_size.value is None:
    raise ValueError("Could not infer input size from input: %s" % inp.name)
  x = linear([inp] + attns, input_size, True)
  # Run the RNN.
  cell_output, state = cell(x, state)
  ....
```

2. Attention states are combined with decoder inputs via learned linear combinations

   `x = linear([inp] + attns, input_size, True)`

   `# Run the RNN.`

   `cell_output, state = cell(x, state)`

...the `linear()` does the W, b matrix operations to down rank the combined input + attn into the decoder input_size. The model will learn values for W and b.

Summary: the attention states are combined with inputs into the decoder, but the last hidden state of the encoder is fed in as the initial hidden state of the decoder without attention.

Finally, the attention mechanism still has the last encoding state at it's disposal and would only "bypass" it if learned that was the best thing to do during training.

Comment: Thx for your reply. 

Yes I am using the seq2seq-Model. Here the attention mechanism, it says in the code, is based on the Gramar as a foreign language (http://arxiv.org/pdf/1412.7449v3.pdf). In that paper I understand that the attention decoder looks into the encoder (", to produce each output symbol Bt, uses an attention mechanism over the encoder LSTM states.").

Comment: By bypassing I dont mean ignore. I would assume the "main" input to the decoder is the encoder_state (at end of encoding). However, if the decoder ALSO uses the attention to directly peep into the encoder-side, then the encopder_state does not necessarily carry ALL the info the decoder uses - thus partially bypassing the encoder_state. 

So if my goal is to use the encoder_state for other learning-tasks I should better switch off attention as this allows the sec2sec to only partially encode all relevant info into the encoder state.